# web3 and web3 provider engine

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, web3-providers

Scenario:

1. Import json file and decrypt it
2. Use account to sign the messsage

I can do this with web3(Web3.providers.HttpProvider) or with web3-provider-engine. What is major difference between using web3 or web3-provider engine?
When should i use web3 provider engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Web3](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) is a library that allows talking to an ethereum node easily from javascript.

[Web3 ProviderEngine](https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine) enhances that functionality. In web3 v0.20 is was required if you wanted to implement a thin client over a public node like infura. But with Web3 v1.0 some of the functionality of *Web3 ProviderEngine* was reimplemented at web3 v1.0.

I'd suggest to try if web3 v1.0 works for you then I'd use that version.